# TinyMCE: formats change (“Paragraph”, “Heading 1”, etc.) is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code initialization:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "td",
  inline: true,
  menubar: false,
  statusbar: false,
  branding: false,
  browser_spellcheck: true,
  toolbar: 'undo redo bold  italic underline | fontselect formatselect  fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | superscript subscript | bullist numlist | link | code',
  plugins: ['code', 'textcolor', 'link']
});
```

Comment: when onchaneing formatselect H1,H2,H3..ect given selectd text is not changed. i am useing tinymce 4.7.4 version.

Comment: Note: selector: "td"

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a fiddle or codesnipet?